# Haskell + Persistent: parse error possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, haskell-persistent

I have been learning Haskell for the last several months and am trying to follow along with this tutorial on Haskell + Persistent:

https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent_code_generation

```
module Main where

{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

mkPersist sqlSettings [persistLowerCase| 
Person
    name String
    age Int
    deriving Show
|]
```

I have not come across this syntax before (they talk about 'QuasiQuotes' in the tutorial so I'm guessing that is what this is), but I think as I have taken the code directly from the tutorial it should compile. However, it won't, and I get the following error:

```
/home/will/programming/learn-haskell/postgres-example/app/Main.hs:15:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
15 | Person
   | ^


--  While building package postgres-example-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/will/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.0.1.0 build exe:simple --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Here is my configuration inside of my cabal file:

```
name:                                postgres-example
version:                             0.1.0.0
synopsis:                            An example of using Haskell and PostGres with persistent
description:                         Please see README.md
license:                             BSD3
license-file:                        LICENSE
author:                              Will Taylor
copyright:                           2020, Will Taylor
category:                            Web
build-type:                          Simple
cabal-version:                       >=1.10

executable simple
  hs-source-dirs:       app
  main-is:              Main.hs
  ghc-options:          -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:        base
                        , persistent
                        , persistent-template
                        , persistent-postgresql
                        , monad-logger
  default-language:       Haskell2010
```

If anyone could help me out then that would be amazing.

Comment: Can you post the full error? I see `possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets` a lot, and often it is a missing `)`.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also a beginner in Haskell. Following the same documentation, I was trying to move the schema definition to another module and import it in main. It simply didn't work with the same error message.

After 2-3 hours of trying out copy/pasting code here and there, and testing it with postgres, I realized something during the process. In the documentation the comments containing Language features appeared on top of file before anything else.

Simply move the comments to the top before everything else

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances       #-}

module Sql.Schema    where

import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.TH


share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    firstName String
    lastName String
    age Int Maybe
    PersonName firstName lastName
    deriving Show
BlogPost
    title String
    authorId PersonId
    deriving Show
|]
```

Comment: You lovely beautiful person! I had actually given up on this as I could not find anything which helped! Such a simple solution to a silly problem - thank you!